# R - Aggregate by hour with max of second value

Tags: r, aggregate

I have data, that i want to aggregate over time steps and additionally want to calculate the max of another value within that group.

For aggregating I'm running the following code:

```
s_stats <- lapply(s_df_array, function(x) {
aggregate(x, by=list(unique.values=x$start), length)
})
```

s_df_array is a table of dataframes and the code does its job fine for counting occurrences of entries for each value in x$start.
Here you can see some of the data:
First data.frame in list:

```
alb.station alb.start alb.km
alb         2         10
alb         2         67
alb         3         23
alb         3         74
alb         3         3
alb         3         15
alb         4         23
alb         4         52
```

Second data.frame in list:

```
alt.station alt.start alt.km
alt         3         25
alt         3         45
alt         4         15
alt         4         10
```

Third data.frame in list: Same structure as 1st and 2nd, but with column-names beginning with "ber."
This goes on for 44 data.frames in this list

Outcome should be something like this for every data.frame in a new list:

```
alb.unique.values alb.station alb.max_km
2                 2           67
3                 4           74
4                 2           52

alt.unique.values alt.station alt.max_km
3                 2           45
4                 2           15
```

and so on for all 44 data.frames

edit: added more examples for list

Comment: You said the column names are starting with 'ber', but in the input tit is 'alb' or 'alt'.  It is confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(alb.station, alb.start) %>% 
   summarise(station = n(), max.km = max(alb.km))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups: alb.station [?]
#    alb.station alb.start station max.km
#   <chr>           <int>   <int>  <dbl>
#1 alb                 2       2   67.0
#2 alb                 3       4   74.0
#3 alb                 4       2   52.0
```

For a list of data.frames

```
map(lst, ~ .x %>%
            group_by(alb.station, alb.start) %>%
            summarise(station = n(), max.km = max(alb.km)))
```

#### Update

If we have a nested `list` of elements, either create a recursive function or use `if/else`

```
map(lst, ~ if(is.data.frame(.x)) .x %>%
        rename_all(funs(sub("^[^.]*\\.", "", .))) %>% 
        group_by(station, start) %>% 
        summarise(n = n(), max.km = max(km)) else map_df(.x, ~ .x %>%
        rename_all(funs(sub("^[^.]*\\.", "", .))) %>%
        group_by(station, start) %>%
        summarise(n = n(), max.km = max(km))))
```

#### data

```
lst <- list(df1, df2, list(df1, df2))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works fine

Comment: Maybe you can help me once more.
The data.frames inside the list have different column names, that i need for further analysis. Is it possible to run the group_by and summarise functions with somethin like column index?

Comment: @Testificator  Sure, let me know

Comment: second data.frame in list:
     alt.station alt.start alt.km
This goes on with alternating columnnames 44 times

Comment: @Testificator  Ok, could you update your post with a small example and expected output

Comment: @Testificator  Your update should work for `df2 %>% group_by(alt.station, alt.start) %>% summarise(alt.station_n = n(), alt.km = max(alt.km))`

Comment: But there is no possibility to run through all 44 data.frames in the list? I am thinking about something like group_by(<placeholder>.station, <placeholder>.start) etc.

Comment: @Testificator  I didn't test the code, but you may need a recursive function `map(df1, ~ if(is.data.frame(.x)) .x %>% rename_all(funs(sub("^[^.]*\\.", "", .))) %>% group_by(station, start) %>% summarise(station = n(), max.km = max(km)) else map(.x, ~ .x %>% rename_all(funs(sub("^[^.]*\\.", "", .))) %>% group_by(station, start) %>% summarise(station = n(), max.km = max(km)))
 )`